# Choosing a column for multiple row queries

Tags: c#, sql

At the moment I am trying to query a broken database in c#. The recently introduced error is that when data is input in a particular way, a value in a column is defaulted to 0, which is problematic for me, as I have no control over what the user does or what the dba does.

To get around this, I have found another path to the data I need to output to the user. Problem is there is I have the requirement from my supervisor to support the old method in the event of the column coming up as a non-zero number.

I am trying to do this with either a case or an if command, but I not that great with sql, so I am not 100% sure where I am going wrong or how to go about it properly/efficiently. These are the commands in their current states:

```
SqlCommand caseCmd = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT H.CREATED, H.STATUSCODE, H.DETAILS, H.YEAR, H.MONTH, H.DAY, H.ITEMTEXT, TC.DOCLE, TC.ICPC, TC.ICD10, TERMCODE =" +
    " CASE H.ITEMCODE WHEN 0" +
    " THEN TN.TERMID" +
    " ELSE H.ITEMCODE END" +
  " FROM " + _databaseName + ".dbo.PASTHISTORY H" +
    " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.TERMNAMES TN ON TN.TERMNAME = H.ITEMTEXT" +
    " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.TERMCODES TC ON TC.TERMID = TERMCODE" +
    " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.CONDITIONS C ON C.TERMID = TERMCODE" +
  " WHERE H.INTERNALID = @patientid" +
    " AND H.RECORDSTATUS = 1" +
    " AND ((H.CREATED >= @mindate) OR ((H.UPDATED IS NOT NULL) AND (H.UPDATED >= @mindate)))" +
    " AND TC.RECORDSTATUS = 1",
  Connection);
caseCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientid", int.Parse(patientId));
caseCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mindate", minEnteredDate);
// Current error:
//   When using 'TC.TERMID = TERMCODE', I get the error 'The conversion of the varchar value 
//   "3951000119103  " overflowed an int column'.
//   This is alleviated by using either TN.TERMID OR H.ITEMCODE

SqlCommand ifCmd = new SqlCommand(
  "IF (H.ITEMCODE = 0)" +
    " SELECT H.CREATED, H.STATUSCODE, H.DETAILS, H.YEAR, H.MONTH, H.DAY, H.ITEMTEXT, TC.DOCLE, TC.ICPC, TC.ICD10, TN.TERMID" +
    " FROM " + _databaseName + ".dbo.PASTHISTORY H" +
      " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.TERMNAMES TN ON TN.TERMNAME = H.ITEMTEXT" +
      " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.TERMCODES TC ON TC.TERMID = TN.TERMID" +
      " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.CONDITIONS C ON C.TERMID = TN.TERMID" +
    " WHERE H.INTERNALID = @patientid" +
      " AND H.RECORDSTATUS = 1" +
      " AND ((H.CREATED >= @mindate) OR ((H.UPDATED IS NOT NULL) AND (H.UPDATED >= @mindate)))" +
      " AND TC.RECORDSTATUS = 1" +
  " ELSE IF (H.ITEMCODE <> 0)" +
    " SELECT H.CREATED, H.STATUSCODE, H.DETAILS, H.YEAR, H.MONTH, H.DAY, H.ITEMTEXT, H.ITEMCODE, TC.DOCLE, TC.ICPC, TC.ICD10" + 
    " FROM " + _databaseName + ".dbo.PASTHISTORY H" +
      " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.TERMCODES TC ON TC.TERMID = H.ITEMCODE" +
      " INNER JOIN " + _drugDatabaseName + ".dbo.CONDITIONS C ON C.TERMID = H.ITEMCODE" +
    " WHERE H.INTERNALID = @patientid" +
      " AND H.RECORDSTATUS = 1" +
      " AND ((H.CREATED >= @mindate) OR ((H.UPDATED IS NOT NULL) AND (H.UPDATED >= @mindate)))" +
      " AND TC.RECORDSTATUS = 1", 
  Connection);
ifCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientid", int.Parse(patientId));
ifCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mindate", minEnteredDate);
// Current error:
//   Getting two lines both saying 'The multi-part identifier "H.ITEMCODE" could not be bound.'
//   I trust this is because of the IF and ELSE IF statements.
//   Starting to think IF isn't the answer for me.

// Use either
SqlDataReader rdr = caseCmd.ExecuteReader();
// or
// SqlDataReader rdr = ifCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Is this even remotely feasible or should I look into just making two sql commands for both alternatives and search through them both?

Comment: As a start, i really recommend you to stop the creating of SQL statements in the C# code, whatever is your case it will be better if you used a stored procedure.

Comment: Is it SQL Server this query is run on?

Comment: While it seems you just went and answered the question anyway (Thank you again), it is absolutely run on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity I took SQL out of C# string and used CTE. Basically, you can first patch the data and then use it for the lookups:

```sql
WITH PatchedHistory AS (
    SELECT 
        H.CREATED, H.STATUSCODE, H.DETAILS, H.YEAR, H.MONTH, H.DAY, H.ITEMTEXT
        , COALESCE(TN.TERMID, H.ITEMCODE) AS ITEMCODE --< TERMID with ITEMCODE fall-back
    FROM _databaseName.dbo.PASTHISTORY H
    LEFT JOIN _drugDatabaseName.dbo.TERMNAMES TN
        ON H.ITEMCODE = 0                             --< Lookup only if ITEMCODE is 0
        AND TN.TERMNAME = H.ITEMTEXT
    WHERE H.INTERNALID = @patientid                   --< Apply most of the filtering here
        AND H.RECORDSTATUS = 1
        AND ((H.CREATED >= @mindate)                  --< Suspicious condition
         OR ((H.UPDATED IS NOT NULL) AND (H.UPDATED >= @mindate))
        )
)
SELECT H.CREATED, H.STATUSCODE, H.DETAILS, H.YEAR, H.MONTH, H.DAY, H.ITEMTEXT, H.ITEMCODE
    , TC.DOCLE, TC.ICPC, TC.ICD10                     --< Add the rest of the data
FROM PatchedHistory H
    INNER JOIN _drugDatabaseName.dbo.TERMCODES TC
        ON TC.TERMID = H.ITEMCODE                     --< Join on the "patched" ITEMCODE
    INNER JOIN _drugDatabaseName.dbo.CONDITIONS C
        ON C.TERMID = H.ITEMCODE                      --< Join on the "patched" ITEMCODE
WHERE TC.RECORDSTATUS = 1
```

Also this condition looks suspicious:

```sql
        AND ((H.CREATED >= @mindate)
         OR ((H.UPDATED IS NOT NULL) AND (H.UPDATED >= @mindate))
        )
```

technically it is equivalent to just

```sql
        AND ((H.CREATED >= @mindate) OR (H.UPDATED >= @mindate))
```

It looks like the intention was

```sql
        AND COALESCE(H.UPDATED, H.CREATED) >= @mindate
```

Comment: You the real MVP. Just tried that all out in and I am getting exactly what I need.

Took your advice on the updated condition. I must admit that I am currently just Frankensteining an old query so I didn't even glance twice at it. Much nicer to look at now.

Also, while I think it may have been done for the sake of my clarity for which I thank you, in the second query would it not be easier to just go with H.* instead of the long train from above?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, `H.*` would work just fine. Enumerating all the fields instead of using `*` can make a query a tad more readable and pays off when converting to view or table-valued function `with schemabinding`, but in this particular case I was just trying to keep the change to the minimum.